# Why can't I access the attr of the javascript object shown in chrome dev tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Like the chrome dev tool's screen shot below, I'd tried

```
console.log(object)
```

to print the total attributes of the object. But I can't access the "depth" through

```
object.depth
```

**but I was able to get the object's name,value,count in the meantime..**

I was wondering what exactly the attr "**depth**" is.

[image]

---

The source code is from a **D3.js tree demo** in this post: [D3.js Drag and Drop, Zoomable, Panning, Collapsible Tree with auto-sizing.](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033)

However, I was trying to customize the algorithm of caculating the the node's width, using each level of the node's max label length instead of the total tree's.

```
// Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
visit(treeData, function(d) {
    totalNodes++;
    maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);

    console.log(d); //I was debuging here
}, function(d) {
    return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
});
```

Comment: What does `JSON.stringify(object)` log?

Comment: Since the top-line summary has exactly 4 properties (name, value, count, children) while the expanded version has many more, it looks like the object is modified after the time the object is logged but before it is expanded in the console. You are probably logging `object.depth` before those modifications take place. Can you provide a complete code sample that fully reproduces your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the replying! I was trying custom a js tree using the d3.js, the source code is from this url: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033)