# getElementsByClassName behaves strangely in chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I've created a content script that does the following:

```
  var stuff = document.getElementsByClassName("actual-log");
  console.log(stuff);
  console.log(stuff[0]);
  console.log(stuff.length);
```

I get the following output:

```
HTMLCollection []0: div.actual-log1: div.actual-log2: div.actual-log3: div.actual-log4: div.actual-log5: div.actual-log6: div.actual-log7: div.actual-log8: div.actual-log9: div.actual-log10: div.actual-log11: div.actual-log12: div.actual-log13: div.actual-log14: div.actual-log15: div.actual-log16: div.actual-log17: div.actual-log18: div.actual-log19: div.actual-log20: div.actual-log21: div.actual-loglength: 22__proto__: HTMLCollection
main.js:4 undefined
0
```

This output seems totally impossible to me. In the first line it is clear that a bunch of results were returned, and that the HTMLCollection that is returned clearly has length 22. The subsequent lines are totally inconsistent with this.

What is going on here?

Comment: HTMLCollection means it's a dynamic collection, re-populated **on access**, that is, when you expand it later in the console.

Comment: Hi, can you execute the same in console of the page ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome displays different object contents on expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031634/chrome-displays-different-object-contents-on-expand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you experience is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a `DynamicNodeList`, meaning it is live and changes to the DOM will be automatically reflected in the collection.

In contrast, using `querySelectorAll` will return a `StaticNodeList`, which is like a snapshot of the DOM at the time the query took place. Any changes that happens after the query will no be reflected in the collection it returns.