# What's the difference between > {} and > {key:value} in Chrome DevTools

Tags: arrays, object, google-chrome-devtools

I am logging out an object to DevTools through the same chain of functions, but it logs differently on the second run.  I am assuming an index or property isn't resetting properly, but am not sure what kind of bug I am looking for.

I see a `i` flag in the first entry, but am unsure how to interpret it.

**Log**

[image]

**Log Expanded**

[image]

Why does it show blank brackets the first time and a more structured preview the second time?  When I expand them out they look the same to me...

Comment: The object in the console is a snapshot of the object at a particular point in time. It's re-evaluated when you expand it. See:  [Chrome displays different object contents on expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031634/chrome-displays-different-object-contents-on-expand)

Comment: Yes, I am confused by why they seem to contain the same content and structure but Chrome tags them differently.