# The values in '{}' are different with when it expand

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD9Wy.png)

Look at the picture. I don't know how it do this. Pay attention to the `price` in the picture. Please tell me the reason.
Thx!

Comment: BTW the duplicate applies to objects too

Comment: Actually, this is a better duplicate (on mobile, so I can't exactly change it): https://stackoverflow.com/q/42031634/5647260