# In console.log output, what does the i stand for?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to clone (by value) a fabric.js object and when I `console.log()` both objects, one has an `i` before it:

```
old-objects i {_objects: Array(56), width: 350, height: 350, toBeParsed: false, minX: -0, …}

new-objects {_objects: Array(56), width: 350, height: 350, toBeParsed: false, minX: -0, …}
```

The new object is created by `newo = Object.assign({}, o);` where `o` is the original fabric.js (5.3) object from `canvas.getObjects()`

Everything else is the same.

The output is copied directly from the console, one object is preceded by an `i` and the clone is not.

The `i` apparently signifies something important to fabric.js because fabric.js does not recognize the clone as valid, even though they are identical in every other aspect.

Note: this is *not* talking about the blue "i" link seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031634/chrome-displays-different-object-contents-on-expand). In my case, the `i` is on the left, is part of the object, is not blue, and is not hoverable.

Comment: *Rereads question*… *Rereads question again*… It sure **looks** like the duplicate is a correct close. I suppose there **might** be a *different* `i` icon (but there's no screen shot of it in the question, and you haven't quoted the text of the tooltip that should appear when you hover it) … and there's no [mcve] in the question.

Comment: There is no tooltip, the icon is not blue, it is on the left and part of the object not the right, the i shows when the object is collapsed and appears to be important for fabric.js to identify it as a fabric object.  other than the color and hoverability, all this was in the original question.

Comment: A screenshot pasted into your question would probably help provide context

Comment: @Retroactives.com While I understood what you were talking about, the question is lacking details that make it completely clear what you're talking about for others.  Could you please provide a screen shot of the log in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` you're seeing before the object's properties is the name of the class that that object is an instance of.  You might be wondering, "who would name a class i?"; well, depending on the context of the library in use, they might not, and that i might as well be a uglified/compressed/minified version of that class.  Which is to say, the class had its name replaced with a single character to reduce the overall size of the library in question.

The `i` does not appear before the cloned object's properties as you don't clone the class itself, just its visible(as in, enumerable) properties.

You can replicate this easily in just your console, but I included a snippet below to illustrate:

```js
class i {
    test1 = 'one';
    test2 = 'two';
}

Object.defineProperty(i, 'test3', {
  value: 'three',
  enumerable: false,
});

const j = new i();

console.log(j);

const k = Object.assign({}, j);

console.log(k);
```

Make sure you check your browser console for the `i` of course.  It won't show up in stack snippets it seems.

[image: Example ran in Brave's console]

Note that this only works in chromium-based browsers; in Firefox for example, it's a bit more clear that its a class, however you have to expand the objects to find it:

[image: Example ran in Firefox's console]

The second way to replicate this is roughly the same, but it involves minifying the code before you execute the code.

Comment: "*Make sure you check your browser console for the i of course. It won't show up in stack snippets it seems.*" I don't see the `i` in my browser console for this code, either. What browser are you using?

Comment: TylerH  In Chrome and variants, it is as Daedalus explained, in Firefox, you have to navigate to the constructor  [ prototype  -> constructor: class i {} ]  vs [ prototype  -> constructor: function Object() ] for the clone.  You will also see the intial has a name  [i] and the clone has a name [object]

Comment: @TylerH As of this moment, I'm using Brave(A chrome variant) v1.59.124.  However, it seems it doesn't show up in Firefox.